# InetRead() and InetGet() return 0 bytes

Tags: http, autoit

I monitor the price of several stores using [`InetRead()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/InetRead.htm) :

```
$data = BinaryToString(InetRead($url,1),4)
```

Some URLs that actually exist return 0 bytes. I tried [`InetGet()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/InetGet.htm) and it does not return any data either. Accessed via browser, the page appears normally. It is returning HTTP status code 202.

```
Global $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")

$oHTTP.Open("GET", $RequestURL, False)
$oHTTP.Send()

If $oHTTP.status == 200 Then
   Return $oHTTP.ResponseText
Else
   Return "ooops... status: " & $oHTTP.status & @LF
EndIf
```

How can I resolve this? This error does not always occur for the same URLs.

Comment: If the Autoit code works, it might be a problem on server side. Try to rerun your code if the error occurs.

Comment: `Sleep(Ping($RequestURL))` (or just `Ping($RequestURL)`) after `$oHTTP.Send()` possibly.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the website is redirecting/blocking by User Agent and/or Referrer string. Using `InetGet()` try changing the User Agent, and forcing a reload by:

```
HttpSetUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36")
InetGet("URL", "filename", 1)
```

Using winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1 object, try:

```
$oHTTP.Open("GET", $RequestURL, False)
$oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36")
$oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Referer", $RequestURL)
$oHTTP.Send()
```

Use your own browser's User Agent string. If this doesn't work get all response headers to narrow down the issue. Add this after `.Send()`, then look at console window:

```
$AllResponseHeaders = $oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders()
ConsoleWrite($AllResponseHeaders)
```